# How to fix this error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'populated')?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose and NodeJS and I want to populate products.

```
const result = await orderModel.find({}).populate({
        path: 'products',
        model: 'products',
        select: {
          quantity: 1,
          unit: 1,
          product: 1
        },
        populate: {
          path: 'product',
          model: 'products',
          select: { type: 1, name: 1 }
        }
      });
      console.log('result', result);
```

this is the orderSchema:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
   type: String,
   required: false
 },
 products: [
       {
         product: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'products', required: false },
         quantity: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },
         unit: { type: String, required: false, default: '' }
       }
     ]
},
{
  timestamps: true
});
const orderModel = mongoose.model('orders', orderSchema);
```

the productSchema:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },    
   type: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   }
}, { timestamps: true });
const productModel = mongoose.model('products', productSchema);
```

the data in database look like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "64e8b34b24bf0243bc87fa82"
    },
    "name": "ORDER 1",
    "products": [
      {
        "quantity": 100,
        "unit": "kg",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "64e8d05a1be39f48906dec4b"
        },
        "product": {
          "$oid": "64e8b34724bf0243bc87fa2f"
        }
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1692971851401"
      }
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1692979290410"
      }
    },
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

I got this error:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'populated')

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'populated')
> at markArraySubdocsPopulated (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\backend\backendNodeJS -
> Copie\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\populate\markArraySubdocsPopulated.js:41:18)
> at assignVals (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\backend\backendNodeJS -
> Copie\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\populate\assignVals.js:195:7)
> at _assign (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\backend\backendNodeJS - Copie\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5119:3)
> at _done (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\backend\backendNodeJS - Copie\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4931:9)
> at _next (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\backend\backendNodeJS - Copie\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4919:7)
> at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\backend\backendNodeJS - Copie\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5028:5
> at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\backend\backendNodeJS -
> Copie\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5
>
> 353:18
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

I tried my code with two users data one works fine and the othrer throw the error.

Comment: Can you share the error details with stack trace?

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN I added the stack trace

Comment: Thanks. I posted solution and root of the problem in my answer. Please see it.

Comment: @DevM there is a typo in your populate method. quanity: 1, shouldn't it be quantity?

Comment: @Nazrul Chowdhury It's a typo 'quantity'

Answer (score 1):

If the products in the database are like this `"products": [null]`

I got the error

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'populated')

I changed to `"products": []` and it worked.

Comment: Hmm interesting, so when element is null it throws error. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mongoose cannot find the document that should be populated. It could be happening because of the way you have defined the ref property in your orderSchema. The ref property should match the model name for the referenced schema. In your case the model name for the productSchema is 'products', but it should be singular, not plural. I am assuming you have exported model as product, not products. If this is indeed the case then you can make the follwoing changes and try.

```js
product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product', required: false }
```

Also in the populate method use the actual model name defined using mongoose.model.

```js
const result = await orderModel.find({}).populate({
  path: 'products',
  model: 'products', // Should be 'product'
  select: {
    quantity: 1,
    unit: 1,
    product: 1
  },
  populate: {
    path: 'product',
    model: 'products', // Should be 'product'
    select: { type: 1, name: 1 }
  }
})
```

Comment: @Nazeul Chowdhury
the productModel  is name is already 'products'
I forgot to add this line in the above description
`const productModel = mongoose.model('products', productSchema);`

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem due to wrong usage of `populate` method.

In your models, orderModel has only a reference to productModel on field `orderModel.products.product`. You want to populate each orders' products' product field.

To accomplish this you have this code:

```js
const result = await orderModel.find({}).populate({
  path: 'products',
  model: 'products',
  select: {
    quanity: 1,
    unit: 1,
    product: 1
  },
  populate: {
    path: 'product',
    model: 'products',
    select: { type: 1, name: 1 }
  }
});
```

This code tries to populate field (or path) `products` in your orderModel objects but `products` field is an array of objects and **is not a reference to another model** that have the following structre:

```js
{
  product: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'products', required: false },
  quantity: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },
  unit: { type: String, required: false, default: '' }
}
```

As you can see, each element in `products` field/array is an object. You need to populate `product` field in each element. To do that, your code should be changed into the following code:

```js
const result = await orderModel.find({}).populate({
  path: 'products.product',
  model: 'products'
});
```

Since the referenced model is specified in your orderSchema, you can shorten the code like this:

```js
const result = await orderModel.find({}).populate('products.product');
```

Comment: I alrady tried that and it did not work

Comment: @DevM hmm, then that's really weird. I ran your codes with my changes and it works fine. I have no idea then :(

Comment: kave you tried my code?

Comment: I think my code is correct.  

can populate work even if there is null values in the database?

Comment: @DevM yes it does. If your any of your orders has null, empty products array that field remain as it is, won't throw an error.

Comment: 'products.product' did not work for me

Comment: I tried my code with two users data one works fine and the othrer throw the error.